# Visualize MNIST dataset using OpenCV or Matplotlib/Pyplot

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, machine-learning, mnist

i have MNIST dataset and i am trying to visualise it using pyplot. The dataset is in `cvs` format where each row is one image of 784 pixels. i want to visualise it in `pyplot` or `opencv` in the 28*28 image format. I am trying directly using :

```
plt.imshow(X[2:],cmap =plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation = "nearest")
```

but i its not working? any ideas on how should i approach this.

Comment: Maybe youd include some more details, showing how you include your data and what exactly is "Not working", this may help you get quicker answers.

Comment: @bakkal ...thanks dude it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Assuming you have a CSV file with this format, which is a format the MNIST dataset is available in

```
label, pixel_1_1, pixel_1_2, ...
```

Here's how you can visulize it in Python with Matplotlib and then OpenCV

### Matplotlib / Pyplot

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('mnist_test_10.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    for data in csv.reader(csv_file):
        # The first column is the label
        label = data[0]

        # The rest of columns are pixels
        pixels = data[1:]

        # Make those columns into a array of 8-bits pixels
        # This array will be of 1D with length 784
        # The pixel intensity values are integers from 0 to 255
        pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype='uint8')

        # Reshape the array into 28 x 28 array (2-dimensional array)
        pixels = pixels.reshape((28, 28))

        # Plot
        plt.title('Label is {label}'.format(label=label))
        plt.imshow(pixels, cmap='gray')
        plt.show()

        break # This stops the loop, I just want to see one
```

[image]

### OpenCV

You can take the `pixels` numpy array from above which is of `dtype='uint8'` (unsigned 8-bits integer) and shape 28 x 28 , and plot with `cv2.imshow()`

```
    title = 'Label is {label}'.format(label=label)

    cv2.imshow(title, pixels)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 8):

Importing necessary packages

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Reading mnist train dataset ( which is csv formatted ) as a pandas dataframe

```
s = pd.read_csv("mnist_train.csv")
```

Converting the pandas dataframe to a numpy matrix

```
data = np.matrix(s)
```

The first column contains the label, so store it in a separate array

```
output = data[:, 0]
```

And delete the first column from the data matrix

```
data = np.delete(data, 0, 1)
```

The first row represents the first image, it is 28X28 image (stored as 784 pixels)

```
img = data[0].reshape(28,28)

# And displaying the image
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

[image: output image]

Answer (score 5):

For all like me who want a quick and dirty solution, simply to get a rough idea what a given input is about, in-console and without fancy libraries:

```
def print_greyscale(pixels, width=28, height=28):
    def get_single_greyscale(pixel):
        val = 232 + round(pixel * 23)
        return '\x1b[48;5;{}m \x1b[0m'.format(int(val))

    for l in range(height):
        line_pixels = pixels[l * width:(l+1) * width]
        print(''.join(get_single_greyscale(p) for p in line_pixels))
```

(expects the input to be shaped like `[784]` and with float values from 0 to 1. If either is not the case, you can easily convert (e.g. `pixels = pixels.reshape((784,))` or `pixels \= 255`)

[image: Output]

The output is a bit distorted but you get the idea.