# Confusion in MNIST dataset visualization using Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, mnist

Few weeks ago when I was preparing the dataset, the visualization of **MNIST images were in gray-scale** even with out using `cmap='Greys'`. But now the **images are displayed in different color** if cmap is not used(image shown below). 

So I am a bit confused on whats going on.

Is it normal? if not what can I do to bring the images to their normal form?

[Preview of the visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvZlJ.png)

Comment: Use cmap='gray' in you plot function and refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/37228371/10077354

Comment: Thank you so much.. But I have no problem is visualizing the image. My actual question is.. "Is the visualization of image with different color as shown in the image above without using cmap normal?"

Comment: Yes it is normal.

Comment: When no colormap is given, matplotlib uses ['viridis'](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) as default. It goes from purple over blue and greens to yellow. The explanation and the history are memorized in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU).